# Chrome 15 and wmode="transparent"

Tags: flash, google-chrome, background, wmode

I have found several related questions here, but none is specific to my problem.
I have and embedded flash object with a "wmode=transparent" parameter.

The background is transparent in all browsers except the latest Chrome. Any idea why this happens?

Here is my code:

```
<object id="flipAlbum" width="100%" height="700" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/plugins/Flipbook/static/flipbook/Default_Flip_Book.swf" style="visibility: visible;">
<param name="align" value="middle">
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
<param name="flashvars" value="xmlPath=/plugin/Flipbook/display/xml/id/10660/locale/de_DE&startPage=1">
</object>
```

Comment: As for me wmode works in IE9, but has no effect in Chrome 19.0.1084.52 m and Safari 5.1.7 for Windows.